# Where is the "generate constructor" option in Eclipse Oxygen?

Tags: php, eclipse, templates, constructor, generator

I'm using Eclipse for PHP and can't find the "generate constructor using fields" option.

It's not in the "Source" menu nor in the right click "Source" context menu. Tried highlighting the class but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Anyone? Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

PDT haven't such feature. Please open enhancement request: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDT